# How does this function swap work? I cant understand it

Tags: function, recursion

I cant understand how the swap function does the swapping

```
void swap(char* p, char* q)
{
 char tmp = *p;
 *p = *q;
 *q = tmp;
}
int h(char* s, int n)
{
 if (s[n]==0) {
 return 0;
 }
 if (s[n+1]==0) {
 return 1;
 }
 int k = h(s+1,n+1);
 swap(s,s+k+1); //how does this work?
 return k+2;
}
void func3()
{
 char s[] = "intro to cs";
 int x = h(s,0);
 printf("x = %d\n", x);
 printf("s = %s\n", s);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
swap(s,s+k+1); //how does this work?
```

Here `s` is a pointer to a chunk of memory that contains a sequence of characters.  The swap function takes two pointers to characters, and takes the values pointed to and swaps them.  In the following example,

```
    |-------|
s   |  'i'  |
    |-------|
s+1 |  'n'  |
    |-------|
s+2 |  't'  |
    |-------|
s+3 |  'r'  |
    |-------|
s+4 |  'o'  |
    |-------|
       ...
```

you could swap the characters `'i'` and `'r'` by calling `swap(s, s+3)`.  This will take the contents of address `s` (`'i'`)and store it in address `s+3`, and vice versa.  In your example, you are using pointer arithmetic.  `s` is a contiguous chunk of memory containing characters (like an array), so you could get the `ith` character in the sequence by doing `s[i]`, or equivalently `*(s + i)`.  `s` is the base address of the string, so to get the address of character `'r'`, we simply add `3` to the base address (`s`)